# How to stop reloading of Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp, tiles

I have an issue with Javascript reloading due to Tiles.

**Tiles-definition.xml**

```
<tiles-definitions>
         <definition name="template-main" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp">
              <put-attribute name="header-main-content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header_main.jsp"/>  
              <put-attribute name="header-quote-content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header_quote.jsp" />
              <put-attribute name="menu-content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/menu.jsp" />
              <put-attribute name="body-content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/slides.jsp" />
              <put-attribute name="footer-content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp" />
         </definition>

         <definition name="template-main-login" extends="template-main">
              <put-attribute name="header-main-content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header_main.jsp" />
         </definition> 
</tiles-definitions>
```

**home.jsp**

```
<body style="background-color: #5F9EA0">

    <head>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/example.js" />"></script>

        bla bla ..
```

**example.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        popUp('show');
    }, 1000);

});
```

**I am using Spring-MVC:**

When the application is loaded I am returning the view as **template-main**. So the first template definition is called and the application is opened with a login popup as I am calling the popup on document load.

**Problem:**

Now when I give the login credentials and submit I am calling **template-main-login** which in turn is extending the **template-main**. Now the problem is, the Javascript which I have included in the home.jsp is loading again (may be since I am extending the template-main layout) such that I am getting the popup opened for the second time which I want to stop.

So please let me know how to stop the popup opening again.

Comment: what are you specifying in the cache headers for the JS files?  What does it show in the browser tools now?

Comment: if using varnish/nginx or even tomcat, you can specify headers for such static files so that they get cached in the browser (either for along duration or via ETags - etags will query the server to see if the file hash is still valid or not).

Comment: @alihaider I am not using any cache headers .. its just a plain js file. Yep I am using Tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest rather than making home.jsp as your template make a separate jsp only for your template and basetemplate will have generic things like loading external js and css files and keep specific js code in specific jsp

Comment: So where will my js be included? Even if I include my js in the base template still I have to extend the base template rt?

Comment: what i am trying to say is as your popup code is specific to your home.jsp so write that part in that jsp only so that it not present in any other jsps and so have no effect

Comment: Okay le me try and check that .. +1 for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your JS files have the proper cache control/expires headers (either set a long date or use ETags).  If you use ETags, the static files will still query the server implementation to check if the file hash has changed or not.  You can avoid that by using expires headers on all your static files so that the browser can cache them and load them from the local computing device as opposed to sending in a HTTP request to your server.